# Display:table-cell losing background color

Tags: html, css

I have created the following code for a product box. I need the middle box to have a red background should no image be present (is for a CMS system), I have used `display: table-cell` so that I can vertically align the images but this seems to be causing an issue. It needs to be semi-responsive too hence the % based width. How I can get that middle image box to have a red background?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/VvwRya?editors=110

HTML:

```
<div class="category-products cf">
  <div class="cp-1">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-260-300-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div><!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div><!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div><!-- .price -->
  </div><!-- .cp-1 -->

  <div class="cp-2">
    <div class="image">

    </div><!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div><!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div><!-- .price -->
  </div><!-- .cp-2 -->

  <div class="cp-3">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-260-300-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div><!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div><!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div><!-- .price -->
  </div><!-- .cp-3 -->  
</div><!-- .category-products -->
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 20px 0;  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.category-products {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cp-1{
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}

.cp-2{
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #666;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.cp-3{
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.image {
  height: 350px;
  width: inherit;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  background: #fe0000;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.price {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` instead of `display: table-cell` ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYyLYW?editors=110)):

```
.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  background: #fe0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use line-height and drop the display thingies *(display:tabe-cell; in order to work properly requires a table / table-row displayed parent)*

Line-height on a single line will set the min-height to your container.

div is block, it will go 100% width.

if empty, insert a inline-block pseudo-element to trigger line-height.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.category-products {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
.cp-1 {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.cp-2 {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #666;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.cp-3 {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.image:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
.image {
  line-height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  background: #fe0000;
}
.image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price {
  font-size: 18px;
}
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-products cf">
  <div class="cp-1">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-260-300-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div>
    <!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div>
    <!-- .price -->
  </div>
  <!-- .cp-1 -->

  <div class="cp-2">
    <div class="image">

    </div>
    <!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div>
    <!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div>
    <!-- .price -->
  </div>
  <!-- .cp-2 -->

  <div class="cp-3">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-260-300-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- .image -->

    <div class="title">
      This Is A Product Title
    </div>
    <!-- .title -->

    <div class="price">
      £10.99
    </div>
    <!-- .price -->
  </div>
  <!-- .cp-3 -->
</div>
<!-- .category-products -->
```